# Sharepoint Online JSOM - Cross Domain Image Issue

Tags: javascript, security, sharepoint, cors

So the issue I am facing is that there is an image sitting on my library at domain:
https://sharepointdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/Documents/file.jpg
When my app loads it alters the domain slightly:
https://sharepointdomain-de0a892752d8c7.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/AppName

And in doing so causes a Cross domain issue, which frustrates me because I can display the image fine, just not convert it into a base64 image.

My code to do that so far is as follows:

```
    function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 55
        canvas.height = 55
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0); 
                 callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    };
    image.src = url;
}
```

With a usage of

```
getDataUri(URL, function (dataUri) {
    alert(dataUri);
});
```

The exact error message is:

Redirect at origin 'Domain Link (Edited as can't have more than two links)' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'Domain Link-de0a892752d8c7' is therefore not allowed access.

Using Javascript Object model. and Office 365 Sharepoint Online

Any help would be great!

Caz

Comment: I wonder if the [`crossorigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#Attributes) attribute on the `<img>` element would help you. Have you tried `image.setAttribute("crossorigin","use-credentials");`?

Comment: I had that thought a while ago, but alas no luck!

Comment: You can't do it without CORS support on the redirected domain.